# What is the difference of "new window" in VS Code's Remote WSL extension and a VS Code window?

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to use a docker container for an application in Windows, but to be able to do so, I need to install WSL. I found that there is a [VS Code's Remote WSL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) and I am not sure the difference between `New Window` in VS Code and in Remote WSL extension.

Example:
New Window in Remote WSL extension in VS Code
[image]

I am new to the below technologies:

- Docker Container
- WSL
- VS Code's Remote WSL extension

Can someone please explain to me what is the difference between invoking V.S. Code in Windows, and invoking V.S. Code in WSL?

**Additional Info:**

To explain how I got to the point where I needed to ask this question, I am including part of my research. I read through the documentation — (that I posted a link to below) — and it is what has led me to contemplate, and seek an answer, for the question that I asked above.

[Remote V.S. Code WSL Extension's Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl)

Comment: I have edited your question to more accuratly reflect what you have shared with me in a comment. I will also update my answer. Plz accept the edit, as it was made to better help you, and I put much time into reformatting it, so I can answer your question in reference to docker, as you did not originally reference the Microsoft App Container in the original question you asked.

Comment: Okay I updated my answer to explain things as thoroughly as I can. Where I actually enjoyed answering this, there is no simple answer that can offer a total understanding for this subject. Much reading and research is needed to understand everything that is happening under the hood of the platforms referenced in this post, and the docker containers. A Computer Science degree is also helpful,

Comment: as the base knowledge gained from presuing such a degree helps people to understand Tech in a way that is dynamic. someone with a CS degree may not know about docker, but would be far more likley to understand the sub-working components of it, without ever having used it, as they understand how the fundamental "lower level" technologies work that are used to develop, implement & invoke Docker Containers.

Comment: Learning a Language like C/C++ or even Assembly is helpful for reasons beyond writing code with the language. Many high-level technologies like docker, can be far better understood by having a working knowledge of the languages that are used to create the higher-level technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of @JAY-DEV answer, I found documentation about the main difference behind the scene between running VSCode in WSL and Windows 10+.

> The first time you try to open VS code in WSL, you'll see is a message
> about "Installing VS Code Server" (the c7d83e57… number is the version
> of the VS Code Server that matches the client-side tools you just
> installed).
>
> VS Code is installing a small server on the Linux side that the
> desktop VS Code will then talk to. That server will then install and
> host extensions in WSL, so that they run in the context of the tools
> and frameworks installed in WSL.
>
> In other words, your language extensions will run against the tools
> and frameworks installed in WSL, not against what is installed on the
> Windows side, as it should for the proper development experience.

To answer the question, when open VS code in WSL, the VS code is still installed and running in Windows and there is a VS Code Server running in Linux communicating to it.

Ref. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial#_run-in-wsl

Answer (score 1):

---

## Difference between running VSCode in WSL and Windows 10

---

Before answering this question, which asks what the differences are between 2 platforms (`Windows 10` & *`"Linux when running in a Windows Subsystem"`*), and why the later is needed for `Docker Containers` I need to first make sure that, those who read this, know what WSL is, and what the acronym `W.S.L.` means, and furthermore; I want to define what ***`Docker`*** is.

###### WSL Defined:

> ###### WSL is an acronym that abbreviates the name ***`"Windows Subsystem for Linux"`***. In a nutshell, The ***`"Windows Subsystem for Linux"`*** allows developers to work in a Linux (or GNU) environment while booted in the Windows 10 Operating system. All Windows10 Editions of Windows have WSL support, except or `Windows 10 S`.

###### Docker Defined:

> ###### Docker is a platform as a service, aka `PaaS` that virtualizes an Operating system as an Environment for where an application can run.

###### So why does Docker require WSL?

> Well technically it doesn't require WSL. If you use Ubuntu as the operating system that your machine boots to, you wouldn't need WSL, however if you are using Windows 10, you would then need WSL (Windows 10S does not support Docker or WSL). The reason WSL is needed when your using windows, is becuase **Docker needs Linux**, which as explained above, WSL is a means in which a Linux Environment can be used by developers when the developers machine is booted to a Windows 10 Operating System.  Docker uses the `Linux kernel`, as well as other parts of Linux, such as the `Linux SHELL` for the platform of the containers becuase they are light weight, and less resource intensive than platforms like Windows 10.

Why someone would prefer to use WSL over Windows 10 is strictly opinioned based, and will not be discussed in this answer, however I will name some of the reasons why WSL is different to use for V.S. Code, than just windows w/o WSL is.

##### Differences & Features

> ###### The biggest difference between running V.S. Code inside of a Windows Subsystem that runs Linux, is that V.S. Code is by definition running in a Linux environment. In other words, if you just start V.S. Code from the start menu without using WSL to invoke it, your environment with-in the Editor will be a windows environment, consequently, you will have a windows PowerShell Console, and in WSL you will have a SHELL for a console. Because the environments are different, the tools, languages & features available to you will be different.
>
> ###### WSL is essentially a tool for those who like to use windows as an operating system, but need, or prefer, to use a Linux platform for development. Before WSL I, and countless others had to dual-boot Linux & windows on a partitioned HDD hard-drive, which was really a pain in the  caboose. Some of the other things that WSL offers is the ability to **"Share Resources"**, Command-line (CLI) tools, such as `grep`, software like `Vim`, and more.
>
> ---

##### Final Note:

I wrote much more about WSL because lets face it, you didn't come here to read what windows was relative to WSL, it was the other way around. With that said, it might seem like WSL adds a bunch of stuff on top of the Windows platform, when developers invoke V.S. Code via WSL, but that type of thinking is wrong, and I don't want to give that impression. If you develop you have been developing your applications in a standard Microsoft Windows environment, and you have always done that, then I suggest continuing to do that. WSL is for those who prefer Linux, or want to take advantage of things that Linux offers (which I named a few above.)

That should give you a helpful idea. If you want to learn more, don't ask, or search about WSL, just research development in a Linux environment, you will learn a lot more about this subject by researching it that way.

---

###### Sources:

1. **Wikipedia on Docker:**  [*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker*(software)_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software))

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, maybe I should mention the reason I try wsl2 and actually I want to work with docker container based project in windows.

Comment: IMO, any and everyone new to Linux should use Ubuntu. Setup WSL using ubuntu. You can grab the Ubuntu v20.04LTS Disto for Windows 10/Windows 10 Pro from the Microsoft Store. The Ubuntu  app explains setting up the environment to get it working. After you get it working, simply install the Docker extension to your V.S. Code instance thats running in the Windows Sub-System. After that its up to you to link Docker to Azure. Which brings me to a point. Docker is a container for an Application that is hosted in the cloud via Azure (there are exceptions, but azure is what docker was created for).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I will post an answer.

I think you are traing to find a tool as the "[Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl)" extension, this will allows you to work with a container while you are developing.

The [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-tutorial) could be a good starting point.

Sorry for the lack of detail in my answer, I just discover this vs code extension and found your question in the process of search information

I will back to this answer and expand it.